# Is it possible to dynamically add a slide to an existing Materialize Carousel?

Tags: materialize

I am able to create a carousel as described [here](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html).  The carousel appears and works properly.

Later on I would like to add an additional slide:
`$(".carousel").append('<a class="carousel-item active" href="#six!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/6"></a>');`

However, this does not appear to work as the slide does not get added to the carousel.

Is adding slides to an initialized carousel not supported or is this an issue on my end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it is. I haven't seen any solution in the internet. I believe that there might be a better and smoother solution but this one is mine.

All you need to do is after adding your new items remove the `initialized` class from already initialized main carousel div and reinitialize it.

```
//init carousel
var slider = $('.carousel');
slider.carousel();

//add a new item
slider.append('<a class="carousel-item active" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>');

//remove the 'initialized' class which prevents slider from initializing itself again when it's not needed
if (slider.hasClass('initialized')){
    slider.removeClass('initialized')
}

//just reinit the carousel
slider.carousel();
```

full working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tq4ycm3/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wavtace7/1/) based on your solution but with faster loading images to show the effect.

Comment: @PavelPotoplyak is there any way to maintain the previous state? when you reinitialize it, the slider goes to the first slide. is there any way to get which slide we are?

Comment: got it, we can use `onCycleTo` callback function

Comment: (not available in the documentation but provided in the code comments.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I'm using the slider. (http://materializecss.com/media.html#slider)

To resolve this, it was necessary to **clear all items**, **re-add items** with the new one, and then **re-bind the slider**.

Follow example: https://codepen.io/troits/pen/QvdZov

```js
let itens = [];
function addItem(){  
  $('.slides').empty();
  $('.slider > .indicators').detach();

  itens.push(createItem());

  for(i in itens){
    $('.slides').append(itens[i]);
  }

  $('.slider').slider();  

  showItem(i);
}

function showItem(i){
  $('.slider > .indicators > .indicator-item')[i].click();
}
```